# In what way is Miroslav Krleža's play Golgota "political in nature"?

Tags: croatian-language, miroslav-krleza, golgota

Miroslav Krleža was one of the most important 20th-century Croatian authors. He published poetry, novels, novellas, short stories and plays. The English [Wikipedia article about him](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=962385638#Works) has the following to say about one of his plays:

> Golgota is another play, political in nature.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

I have not found a source for this statement; the [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=171498395) and the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=201637635) articles about the author don't say anything about the content of this play. In what way is this play "political"? Does it directly or indirectly discuss the political situation in the Austro-Hungarian Empire, which included Croatia at the time? Or is it political in a much more general or abstract sense? And what political stance does the play take?